# http_access.log on WebSphere 6.1.0.29

Tags: java, http, websphere

I am running WebSphere 6.1.0.29 and I need to track the requests being made to an Enterprise Application. Previously I did this by routing the requests through a proxy server, but I need to repeat the exercise and I figure there must be a simpler way.

Does anyone know how to enable HTTP access logging?

I have been through the console an *thought* I had enabled http_access.log and http_error.log via:

Application servers > server1 > HTTP error and NCSA access logging

(where 'server1' is the application server)

I've enabled the service at startup, and ticked the boxes to enable access logging and error logging - however... nothing has happened. I have restarted the server, restarted the Enterprise apps and even did a "find . -name" for the log files - but they don't seem to be anywhere on the system.

I saw on a JavaRanch thread someone suggested writing a custom filter for requests in an application, but this seems like wild overkill - *plus* I am doing the logs to test a pre-built binary, so I don't want to mess with the code.

Anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Help! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should do the job for you.

Have you done this (with respect to the HTTP Channel)

After you configure the HTTP error log and the NCSA  access log, make sure that the Enable NCSA access logging field is selected for the HTTP channels for which you want logging to occur. To view the settings for an HTTP channel, click Servers > Application Servers > server  > Web Container Transport Chains  > HTTP Inbound Channel.

Have a look at this for your reference:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/welcome_nd.html

HTH
Manglu